# NullPointerException at parameters.getSupportedPictureFormats

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-camera

I am building an app that captures images and show them to further manipulate, Below are my code and error log from logcat, what can i do to avoid the null pointer exception ?
I have a button that starts my camera activity and lays out this Preview.
 Please Help, I have spent the whole day but could not find the right way to solve it.

```
public class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback , PictureCallback  {
private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private Camera mCamera;
private RawCallback mRawCallBack;
public Preview(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    //mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    mRawCallBack = new RawCallback();

    setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mCamera.takePicture(mRawCallBack, mRawCallBack, null, Preview.this);
        }
    });


}



@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    parameters.setPreviewSize(width, height);
    mCamera.startPreview();
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mCamera = Camera.open();
    configure(mCamera);
    try{
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
    } catch(IOException exception){
        closeCamera();

    }
}

private void closeCamera() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(mCamera != null){
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;

    }
}




private void configure(Camera camera) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();

    //configure in RGB format
    List<Integer> formats = params.getSupportedPictureFormats();


    if(formats.contains(ImageFormat.RGB_565))
        params.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.RGB_565);
    else if(formats.contains(ImageFormat.JPEG))
        params.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
    else if(formats.contains(ImageFormat.YUY2))
        params.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.YUY2);
    else if(formats.contains(ImageFormat.YV12))
        params.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.YV12);
    else if(formats.contains(ImageFormat.NV16))
        params.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.NV16);
    else if(formats.contains(ImageFormat.NV21))
        params.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.NV21);

    // biggest Picture Support from hardware
    List<Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
    Camera.Size size = sizes.get(sizes.size()-1);
    params.setPictureSize(size.width, size.height);

    List<String> flashModes = params.getSupportedFlashModes();
    if(flashModes.size() > 0)
        params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
    //for fast moving objects, would be null if fullscreen mode is not supported
    List<String> sceneModes = params.getSupportedSceneModes();
    if(sceneModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.SCENE_MODE_ACTION))
        params.setSceneMode(Camera.Parameters.SCENE_MODE_ACTION);
    else
        params.setSceneMode(Camera.Parameters.SCENE_MODE_AUTO);
    params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_FIXED);
    camera.setParameters(params);


}



@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    closeCamera();
}

@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] jpeg, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mCamera.startPreview();


}
```

Here is the log

```
03-07 00:33:03.658: D/gralloc_goldfish(1231): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
03-07 00:33:13.248: D/AndroidRuntime(1231): Shutting down VM
03-07 00:33:13.248: W/dalvikvm(1231): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb67ad4f0)

03-07 00:33:13.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1231): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    03-07 00:33:13.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1231): java.lang.NullPointerException
    03-07 00:33:13.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at android.hardware.Camera$Parameters.getSupportedPictureFormats(Camera.java:1721)
    03-07 00:33:13.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at com.in2gravity.smartdoc.Preview.configure(Preview.java:81)
    03-07 00:33:13.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at com.in2gravity.smartdoc.Preview.surfaceCreated(Preview.java:54)
    03-07 00:33:13.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:543)
    03-07 00:33:13.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at android.view.SurfaceView.dispatchDraw(SurfaceView.java:348)
    03-07 00:33:13.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
    03-07 00:33:13.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
    03-07 00:33:13.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
    03-07 00:33:13.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
    03-07 00:33:13.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
    03-07 00:33:13.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
    03-07 00:33:13.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
    03-07 00:33:13.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
    03-07 00:33:13.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1862)
    03-07 00:33:13.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1522)
    03-07 00:33:13.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1258)
    03-07 00:33:13.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
    03-07 00:33:13.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    03-07 00:33:13.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    03-07 00:33:13.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    03-07 00:33:13.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    03-07 00:33:13.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    03-07 00:33:13.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    03-07 00:33:13.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    03-07 00:33:13.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: i think this is not all logcat error, must have some line more

Comment: @Shayan i have added the first three lines that i missed to enlist

Comment: you dont have any error after last line?

Comment: were you running this on an emulator? of course it crashed!

Comment: please indicate line 81 @ `Preview` class

Comment: @thepoosh ICS emulator supports camera.

Comment: @shayan it did not show any other error line in the log cat

Comment: @thepoosh i tried to to run it in a real device to, but it stopped

Comment: @Rakibul, please add logcat for actual device

Comment: @WilliamRiley how do you know what emulator he's using and what API level?

Comment: @thepoosh I don't presume to know, however you should not just tell him that it will crash on any emulator for that reason, because you sir, are wrong. Have a nice day.

Comment: I am using the default emulator and using api 10 , is that a problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like surfaceChanged is maybe getting called before mCamera is created? Could be a timing thing. Put a try/throw null check in surfaceChanged and try it out.